# Differences between "je trouve ça..." and "je trouve que..."

Tags: usage

Are there any differences between them? Do they both mean "I think that..." in English? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're not interchangeable.

"*je trouve ça*" is followed by **an adjective**, and can be translated by "*I find it ...*" rather than by "*I think that ...*".

> Je trouve ça **beau** = *I think it's beautiful*
>
> Je trouve ça **bizarre** qu'il soit parti aussi vite = *I find it weird that he left so quickly*

"*je trouve que*" is followed by **a clause**. *that* is often omitted in English.

> Je trouve que **tu devrais faire plus d'efforts** = *I think you should make more efforts*
>
> Je trouve que **ça te va bien** = *I think it looks good on you*

---

Note that you can "transform" sentences with *je trouve ça* to use *je trouve que* by adding *c'est* before the adjective, making it a clause.

> Je trouve **ça bizarre**
>
> Je trouve **que c'est bizarre**